# XPath select child elements that do not have a specific element

Tags: xml, xpath

example i have

```
<a>
   <test>
         <name>h</name>
   </test>
   <test2>
         <name>s</name>
   </test2>
   <test3/>
</a>
```

i want to select the test where don't have name element inside
what i done so far:

```
/a/test/*[not(self::name)]
```

expected output should be only test3 will be display, but what in my program its display all include test,test2 and test3. any error on my coding?

Answer (score 2):

Use `/a/*[not(name)]`, that selects all child elements of the `a` root element that don't have a `name` child element.

Answer (score 0):

This will look for any elements that are children of the `a` element which start with the name 'test' and which do not have child elements named `name`:

```
/a/element()[starts-with(local-name(.), 'test')][not(child::name)]
```